# Possibility of using python method in C++ project

Tags: python, c++, boost

Python has a very useful optimization library called `nevergrad`, which I wanted to try using in a project written in C++. A simple test case on `nevergrad`:

```
import nevergrad as ng

# optimization function
def square(x): 
    return sum((x - 0.5) ** 2)

# solve method
def solve():
    optimizer = ng.optimizers.NGOpt(parametrization=2, budget=100)
    return optimizer.minimize(square).value
```

The peculiarity of my task is that the minimization function that I want to use instead of square must call a method from the C++ project. Visually it looks like this:
[image: scheme of calls]

If the call from C++ is done using Embedded Python, then the reverse call is done using `boost.python`. But the difficulty is that the C++ project has already been launched by the time it accesses python, and `Class 2` has been initialized accordingly. However, in most `boost.python` usage examples, the C++ class initialization is done in python.

Is it possible to execute the sequence of calls shown in the picture C++ > Python > C++ and get the result in reverse order?

Comment: Well yes, like you noticed, you can embed python in C++, and you can create python bindings from C++ (imho [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) is the easiest way). So, just chose your principal language and do it. It doesn't matter how many python or C++ functions are you going to call and in which order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try this out by myself, but reading the boost.Python docs, I guess the following approach should work (at least, in principle):

- In your C++ code, instantiate your Class2 object as a [wrapped object](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/object.html#tutorial.object.derived_object_types.class_t_as_objects):

  ```
  object myClass2Object = (class_<Class2> ...,
  ```
- [start the embedded Python interpreter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html#tutorial.embedding.getting_started) and create the `__main__` module
- retrieve the main namespace and add your Class2 object to it:

  ```
  object main_module = import("__main__");
  object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
  main_namespace["myClass2Object"]=myClass2Object;
  ```
- import `nevergrad` into the interpreter as well as a Python `solve` function which expects a `myClass2Object` in the main namespace and uses it as for the target function
- use [exec or eval](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html#tutorial.embedding.using_the_interpreter.running_python_code) to call the solve function

  ```
  object result = eval("solve()", main_namespace);
  ```

  and [extract](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html#tutorial.embedding.using_the_interpreter.manipulating_python_objects) the results into native C++ variables from there.

It would be nice if you can tell me how far this works, or if I am off-track with this answer.

Comment: I finally did everything I asked in the question. Your answer made it much easier for me to understand and find information Thank you! I added my own result as an answer, as there is more editing capability

Answer (score 0):

Given answer is slightly different from what I described in the question. I wrote a method in `Class1` that calls method from `Class2` to get the optimization function result (class2 obj is property of class1).

Calls order: `RunOpt() > solve() > function() > GetFunctionValue()`

C++ code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::python;

double Class1::GetFunctionValue(std::vector<double> x_point) {
    // some logic, which call class2 obj method and calculates res from x_point
    return res;
}

void Class1::RunOpt(){
    // start interpreter
    Py_InitializeEx(0);
    try {
        // register iterable conversions
        iterable_converter()
                .from_python<std::vector<double>>();
        bp::class_<std::vector<double>>("std_vector_double")
                .def(bp::vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<double>>());
        // bind class
        bp::class_<Class1, boost::noncopyable>("class_1", bp::no_init)
                .def("get_function_value", &Class1::GetFunctionValue);

        // retrieve the main module.
        bp::object main_module(bp::import("__main__"));
        // retrieve the main module's namespace
        bp::object main_namespace(main_module.attr("__dict__"));

        // ADD ARGUMENTS
        main_module.attr("class_1_obj") = bp::object(bp::ptr(this));
        main_module.attr("parametrization_val") = num_param; // variables count

        // PYTHON CODE
        bp::exec_file("py_opt.py", main_namespace, main_namespace);
        // get result
        bp::object solve = main_namespace["solve"];
        result = bp::extract<std::vector<double>>(solve());
    } catch(const bp::error_already_set &) {
        // python errors processing
        PyObject* ptype = nullptr;
        PyObject* pvalue = nullptr;
        PyObject* ptraceback = nullptr;

        bp::object formatted_list, formatted;
        PyErr_Fetch(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);

        PyErr_NormalizeException(&ptype, &pvalue, &ptraceback);
        bp::handle<> htype(ptype);
        bp::handle<> hvalue(bp::allow_null(pvalue));
        bp::handle<> htraceback(bp::allow_null(ptraceback));

        bp::object traceback(bp::import("traceback"));
        if (!ptraceback) {
            bp::object format_exception_only(traceback.attr("format_exception_only"));
            formatted_list = format_exception_only(htype, hvalue);
        } else {
            bp::object format_exception(traceback.attr("format_exception"));
            formatted_list = format_exception(htype, hvalue, htraceback);
        }
        formatted = bp::str("\n").join(formatted_list);
        std::string error_str = boost::python::extract<std::string>(formatted);
        std::cout << error_str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Python code (`py_opt.py`):

```
# from c++: class_1_obj, parametrization_val
import nevergrad as ng

def function(x):
    return class_1_obj.get_function_value(x.tolist())

def solve():
    optimizer = ng.optimizers.registry['NGOpt'](parametrization=parametrization_val, budget=100)
    recommendation = optimizer.minimize(function)
    return recommendation.value
```

Comment: This answer will be more useful if you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, with each header and source file that you have in your actual code(remove the not necessary part ofcourse) and similarly add all the python files you have. Because looking at your answer, I don't see any header file where class definitions are there.